# Бесконечный Шум Перлина в python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Мне для разработки игры нужно использовать Шум Перлина, но мне нужна функция для бесконечного шума. То есть она должна принимать в качестве параметров: seed - ключ по которому будет генерироваться шум; x и y координаты точек.
Выдавать в конце он должен число от 0 до 255. То есть для игры высоту точки с данными кординатами.
Вот нормальный Шум Перлина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как я не нашёл способа создания в python бесконечного Шума Перлина, попытался создать свой, но получилось совсем не то, и очень медленно:

[image: Вот мой код и результат.]

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить это. Мне детальность шума особо не важна если сильно замедляется.

Мне нужно что-то вроде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете подсмотреть реализацию тут: https://github.com/caseman/noise

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43094/discussion-on-question-by-mihail-ris-----python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге я просто установил библиотеку noise `pip install noise` в терминале, затем по совету пользователя andreymal в скрипте уменьшил координаты точек на 0.05 и вместо seed выбрал 3D шум вместо 2D в котором вместо оси Z подставил seed. Получилось:

```
import noise

s = noise.pnoise3(float(x)*0.05, float(y)*0.05, seed, 1)
```

Где 1 - детальность шума.

```
s = s*100.0
```

Это для удобства использования.

Также библиотеку noise можно скачать на сайте https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/